# Genetic personality

Tags: science-based, magic, humans, psychology

I want a family of humans born with insticts that come fron their parents.

Father smithsman and mother vampire hunter = child attracted to metalworking and with a natural hate and instincts to murder vampires.

What must be tweeked in the human DNA to make it possible?
do I just handwave it with magic?

Comment: could the parents not raise the child? usually that has a large effect on ones personality.

Comment: Whether you choose to handwave it with magic, explain it away with pseudoscience, or try to justify it with an explanation based in science is a stylistic choice you get to make when building your world.

Comment: this is completely possible, and we know that because domestication has demonstrated that manners, behavior, and even intelligence and skills, are at least partially hereditary.

Comment: The problem with trying to do it with instincts is that humans incredibly go far beyond instincts. We are wired to adapt and learn while communicating what we have learned to others. Among mammals, hunters have far fewer instincts than prey do because we have to adapt on the fly. So, instead of instincts, work with being taught patterns of thought and actions.

Comment: @DavidR when an animal hunter sees a puppy for the first time the first Instinct is to kill and eat that sweet smelling walking candy... Most humans don't go around killing small dogs and cats on the streets and I doubt it was ever different, but probably in your city it is normal for children to bloodlust for various puppies instead of cuddles... Every culture is different.

Comment: Sorry, its just that every times someone compares humans to predators I cringe.... Humans are as good predators as a cow with opposable fingers and a riffle...they eat meat sometimes, they might aswell surpass us.

Answer (score 6):

### Not so Simple Answer: Not *Realistically* Possible, but not Theoretically *Im*possible

Instinct is a huge, thorny issue for biologists. Everyone can see things that function as what is normally thought of as instinct, but when you get down to it, no one can definitively prove absolute instinct. What everyone CAN agree is that the environmental interaction with genetics and development can lead very specific organisms towards behaviors in a mostly reproducible way. [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5182125/) is an excellent article in reasonably plain English explaining the problems and issues.

- Humans do not generally exhibit the behaviors thought of as instincts. There are predispositions, but these are greatly influenced by a wide variety of factors. They are not completely reproducible even with [twin studies](https://voices.uchicago.edu/dfiwellnews/2020/04/13/nature-vs-nurture-how-twins-can-help-us-understand-the-microbiome/), although these studies are quite fascinating. Remember that with twin studies there is an identical developmental environment for the first critical period of development, challenging the genetics assumptions.
- Instincts apply across entire species. To have two groups of people with different sets of instincts implies they are functionally different species. When these species interact, the resulting instincts might have very different outcomes. [Pheasants and grouse](https://retrieverman.net/2019/01/29/the-strange-hybrid-between-a-pheasant-and-a-blue-grouse/) are biologically able to interbreed, but the offspring that result have extremely confused mating practices that prevent them from mating with either species.
- The genetics of instincts, and even the acceptance of true instincts as a separate thing, are not worked out in any species I know of, except in some extremely primitive organisms, and are only understood when fairly macroscopic behaviors are easily documentable. The subtle behaviors of 'what makes a good blacksmith' and 'what makes a good vampire hunter' are too murky to have in the category of true instincts.

That being said, there is nothing to say you can't handwave a set of behaviors from your smith/vampire hunter, but don't assume that they could pick up a hammer, make a sword, and decapitate the first vampire they encounter without having a lifetime of experiences to reinforce the underlying predilections. Mom and dad would have done most of the training for this, but if the kid was raised by uncle Otto the goatherder instead after Mom and Dad's tragic death, then the kid might make a good blacksmith or vampire hunter given the right training. If uncle Otto never told the kid what Mom & Dad did, or he spoke well of vampires and poorly of blacksmiths, then the kid will be unlikely to ever follow those paths.

Comment: Humans **do** exhibit innate instinctive behaviors, notably the grasping instinct of newborns (they close their hands when you put a finger on it) and, like all mammals, sucking milk. The second is universal mammalian, the first is specific to primates (where it serves to anchor the newborn on its mother's fur; we don't have suitable fur, so it is not so useful in humans.) But yes, by and large mammals are very very much less driven by instincts than reptiles or birds.

Comment: @AlexP that's why I specified that humans do not generally exhibit instinctive behaviors, and some biologists are increasingly defining these responses as reflexes rather than instincts. It's a fine line. Read the first article, it's pretty good.

Comment: @AlexP Infant reflexes do not last. Most of the reflexes that persist into adulthood are physical responses related to proper body functioning such as coughing and blinking. As for complex instinctive behaviours, humans have almost none. The ones that still remain are mostly associated with reproduction, however, there is more and more evidence that they are affected by emotional states and, thus, differ a lot from instinctive behaviours exhibited by other species.

Answer (score 3):

No magic needed! The way people are taught and raised can easily work to your benefit through socialization and psychology. Usually, during socialization, children will learn things from their parents. But children are also their own people.

If this child is close to their parents and their parents are verbal about their work it is easy to explain it via socialization. Since a child's first memories and important growth periods are *usually* with their parents, their parent's interests and opinions would affect their own.

Take the father. He is a smith. So maybe he needs the child's help and/or is teaching them his trade. This used to be incredibly common historically and today when trades were/are highly specialized. If he has a specific way of doing things it would be even more reasonable. If you are writing in a pre-modern era setting this would be likely all over the planet (though depending on the trade, more women or men would be in it (ick, misogyny)).

The mother, as stated, hunts vampires. So if she verbally speaks of this work and *especially* if she verbalizes hate and her husband is okay with it, the child may easily grow to have these opinions as well. While a proclivity to murder has more psychological effects and differences, as well as murder easily changing the way people think, dislike and hate would easily be the child's personality if introduced to it by their mother at a young age.

Additionally, if the murder/hunting of vampires is common and considered a job or profession in your story/world, the draw of hunting vampires would not be unlikely for a child. Especially with a parent regularly discussing and performing this occupation.

One important aspect is the chosen gender and sexual orientation of the character along with the system they are in. A culture that differentiates feminity from masculinity and assigns specific roles, jobs, and traits to them respectively may see greater extremes or stereotypes that may affect the character and what they do. Along with the way they think.

Answer (score 1):

As DWKraus said, genetic personality as you want it is not realistically possible. There are way too many factors involved in human personality development and genomes only provide some foundation. Moreover, genes associated with certain personality traits are often linked to other genes. A slight change in gene expression due to environmental factors leads to cascade effects in all other linked genes.

If you want to have a somewhat 'genetic' explanation you could go with the idea of bloodline inheritance. It is not scientific and does not exist in reality, as far as I know. However, something like this would explain how children have the same 'instinctive' drives as their parents. Awakening of these bloodlines, their mixing/clashing can be an interesting part of your story.

Bloodlines and their purity would also explain why certain behaviours are limited to specific families/people and do not spread among the rest of the population.